# Updating data from view model mvc5 (EF6)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, controllers

I have a problem when I Update the database from model! 
I have an interface and I identify an Edit Function  and I created a class to implement this function as follow:

```
public void Edit(byte? id)
{
       var entity = getByID(id);
       UnitOfWork.DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
       UnitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

In the controller I called this function as follow:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(BackendModuleViewModel model)
{
       var entity = model.ConvertToEntity(model);
       _backendModuleRepository.Edit(entity.BNM_ID);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

When I run the project it tells me that the primary key is null !

The function (getByID) in Edit that located in a repository is implemented as follow:

```
public BackendModule getByID(byte? id) 
{ 
      var entity = DbSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BNM_ID == id); 
      return entity; 
}
```

Comment: The function (getByID) in Edit that located in a repository is implemented as follow:        public BackendModule getByID(byte? id)
        {
            var entity = DbSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BNM_ID == id);
            return entity;
        }

Comment: I don't see where you're actually updating anything...you appear to be getting an entity out of the db, setting it's status to modified and committing it again. The only thing you use from the model is the ID.